# coudn't find location of python module

Tags: python, module

I'm working with ubuntu, and it gives following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/licensing.py", line 559, in <module>
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/application.py", line 151, in run
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/licensing.py", line 155, in execute
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/licensing.py", line 228, in runCurrentUsageApp
  File "SMAPyrModules/SMAPyrUtiPy.m/src/uti.py", line 37, in spawnAndWait
  File "SMAPyrModules/SMAPyrUtiPy.m/src/utiSpawn.py", line 93, in spawnAndWait
  File "SMAPyrModules/SMAPyrUtiPy.m/src/utiSpawnImpl.py", line 643, in spawnAndWait
  File "SMAPyrModules/SMAPyrUtiPy.m/src/utiSpawnImpl.py", line 477, in __init__
  File "SMAPyrModules/SMAPyrUtiPy.m/src/utiSpawnImpl.py", line 438, in popenWrap
```

I cannot find the SMAPyModules directory as well as modules such as licensing.py, utiSpawn.py etc.

Could you give me some solution or advice?

Comment: What were you trying to do when it thrown Error?

Comment: I'm trying to check abaqus license status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console:

```
sudo apt install lsb
```